# Zero value orders

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice

Hi We have a number of orders come through where customers have bought an item, paid for it successfully, but the total on the invoice is inexplicably zero.

The invoice states the item has sold for example £10, but then the invoice total shows zero.

How / why can this occur, and how can it be stopped?[image: item price is zero (it isn't!)]

Comment: Are you having any 3rd party extensions that may be dealing with checkout/add to cart process ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Sorry if I've wasted anyone's time!

There's nothing actually broken.  The zero value orders are all orders which have been manually edited by shop staff to replace items which have gone missing in the post!

I feel stupid now!